# python mask for different size numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have three numpy arrays:

```
X which is a numpy array with two dimensions (height and width), for example: 1000x2000
Y which is a numpy array with two dimensions (height and width), for example: 1000x2000
Img which is a numpy array that has three dimensions: (height, width, rgb) for example: 1000x2000x3
```

I've created a mask of X and Y, for example: `mask = [Y[:,:]>100, X[:,:]>50]` and I've created a sum of these masks:

```
masks = mask[0] & mask[1]
```

Now I want to select X, Y and Img parts depending on the mask:

```
X_ = X[masks]
Y_ = Y[masks]
```

This works fine, but now I also want to do the same selection for `Img`, however this doesn't work since it is a three dimensional array. How would I use the mask to select the same "fields" just as I do for X and Y?

Comment: What's wrong with `Img[masks,:]`?

Comment: @flebool or even just `Img[mask]` should work thanks to broadcasting.

Comment: for me, even `Img[masks]` works. Python 2.7.5+

Comment: Sure, I was coding blind

Comment: Thanks for making me see my error, it was just a type in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried indexing it in the same way? I believe it should work fine.

```
>>> a = arange(24).reshape(2,4,3)
>>> mask = arange(8).reshape(2,4) < 5
>>> a[mask].shape
(5, 3)
```